# ExtJs calendar icon not showing in xtype datefield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Calendar icon is not showing when I run the code in my local whereas on the Sencha website the same code works ie calendar icon shows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        Ext.onReady(function () {
            basicFormPanel();
        });

        function basicFormPanel() {
            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                renderTo: document.body,
                title: 'User Form',
                height: 350,
                width: 300,
                bodyPadding: 10,
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                        name: 'firstName'
                    },
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                        name: 'lastName'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
                        name: 'birthDate'
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me in fiddler. Can you say bit more about problem. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/268m

Comment: yup that's what I said, it's working fine on fiddle but when I try to run it in my local (system), the calendar icon doesn't show. @UDID

Comment: have you checked your browser console, are there  any errors or broken links to your images folder?

Comment: If you have not made folder structure with  Sencha Architect, then have you included path to your extjs folder in your html file ??                      
        eg:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css"
 type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

Comment: or may be try renderTo : Ext.getBody() instead of document.body, although I don't see any reason for it not to work.